# Boolean value won't change in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a Thread and a Swingworker. The Swingworker takes values from the Thread and publishes them in a JPanel.

As I don't want the thread to continue until the Swingworker has taken the value, I stop it in a infinite loop, but when I change the boolean value, the thread doesn't just continue.

This is an example of the problem:

**Swingworker Class**

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void,int> 
{
    Mail m;
    MyJPanel jp;

    public Worker(Mail m, MyJPanel jp)
    {
       this.m = m;
       this.jp = jp;
    }

protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception 
    {
            int letter;


            while(!m.getEnd())
            {


                letter = m.getMail();

                publish(letter);

                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }

            return null;
    }

    protected void process(List<int> chunks) 
    {
         for (int number : chunks) 
         {
              jp.setTextArea("Letter n " + number + " arrived");
         }
     }

}
```

**Mail Class**

```
public class Mail extends Thread
{
  private int delivery;
  private int num;
  private boolean stop = true;
  private boolean end = false;

public Mail(int num)
{
       this.num = num;
}

public void run()
{
       for(int i = 0; i < num;i++)
      {
          doDelivery(i);
      }
     end = true;
}
public void doDelivery(int x)
{
     delivery = x;

     System.out.println("Delivery awaits");

     while(stop);

     System.out.println("Delivery completed");

     stop = true;
}
public int getMail()
{
    System.out.println("Taking the mail"); 

    stop = false;

    return delivery;

}
public boolean getEnd()
{
   return end;
}
```

**Part of the code where threads are started**

```
// being "panel" an extension of JPanel

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
           if(e.getActionCommand().equals("start"))
           {

                   int num = panel.getNum();

                   Mail m = new Mail(num);
                   Worker worker = new Worker(m,panel);

                   m.start();
                   worker.execute();

               }
           }
```

The output in the console would be:

```
Delivery awaits
Taking the mail
//Span of 2 seconds
Taking the mail
Taking the mail
```

While in the textArea is

```
Letter n 0 arrived
Letter n 0 arrived
Letter n 0 arrived
```

I never see "Delivery completed", so even when the Swingworker is changing the loop boolean value, the thread won't get out of it. Why?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: While an MCVE would be nice, just the first paragraph strongly indicated that the variable in question wasn't volatile.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the bool value with a Semaphore, now the Mail Class looks like this.

```
public class Mail extends Thread
{
  private int delivery;
  private int num;
  private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0,true);
  private boolean end = false;

public Mail(int num)
{
       this.num = num;
}

public void run()
{
       for(int i = 0; i < num;i++)
      {
          doDelivery(i);
      }
     end = true;
}
public void doDelivery(int x)
{
     delivery = x;

     System.out.println("Delivery awaits");

      try {

           sem.acquire();

       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {};

     System.out.println("Delivery completed");

}
public int getMail()
{
    System.out.println("Taking the mail"); 

    sem.release();

    return delivery;

}
public boolean getEnd()
{
   return end;
}
```

This seems to work but I'll update if it doesn't.